# SmallCaps with Babel's font loading mechanism in texlive versions prior to TL2022

Tags: luatex, fontspec, babel, small-caps

Please consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Does not work with tl version < 2022 
\usepackage{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[%
  BoldFont = MinionPro-Bold.otf,%
  ItalicFont = MinionPro-It.otf,%
  BoldItalicFont = MinionPro-BoldIt.otf,
  Language=Default,%
  WordSpace = 1.25,%
]{MinionPro-Regular.otf}

%% works with tl2019-2022 
% \usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{MinionPro-Regular.otf}[%
%   BoldFont = MinionPro-Bold.otf,%
%   ItalicFont = MinionPro-It.otf,%
%   BoldItalicFont = MinionPro-BoldIt.otf,
%   Language=Default,%
%   WordSpace = 1.25,%
% ]

\author{}\title{}

\begin{document}

Test \textsc{Test} Test
\end{document}
```

With main font loaded through babel, the small caps don't work:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/MinionPro-Regular.otf(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/MinionPro-Regular.otf(0)/m/n' instead on input li
ne 27.
```

using fontspec's native font loader however, does work with all TL versions from 2019early through 2022.

I also noted that the babel version now works in TL2022, however, I to get it to work with earlier TL versions, as well. I'm using lualatex to compile all trials.

Is there a patch or workaround for those earlier versions of the babel package?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Show the failing log-file from 2021.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer https://pastebin.com/qjBhNwfY

Comment: for comparison same input, TL2022: https://pastebin.com/SWL5y93X

Comment: well then do a comparision. The log tells you even what the problem could be.

Comment: what do you mean? All I see is that the TL2021 says "Font shape `TU/MinionPro-Regular.otf(0)/m/sc' undefined" which TL2022 does not…

Comment: There is a large fontspec warning `Package fontspec Warning: Font 'MinionPro-Regular' is using the ...`. So use a proper diff program and check the whole log for differences regarding the font setup.

Comment: I still don't get it. Apparently the font are okay since the very same font file is used in both TL2021 and TL2022. But babel is able to determine the "correct" font features in 2022 on its own, but is not in 2021. My original question was how to tell earlier babel to set up the correct font features? This is something I can not read from diff-ing both logs…

Comment: Compare the font settings. The working log use `script=latn;language=dflt`. Compare this with the failing log and then check the fontspec docu about which option to use to set the script.

Comment: With additional options `Script=Latin`, i got it to work. Although i appreciate the lecture in interpreting LaTeX's log files, it would have been easier to simply post that as an answer… Thanks, anyway.

Comment: no it wouldn't be easier because next time you would again ask and I would spent time to test, to request log files and to diff them. It is much easier for me if you learn to do this yourself.

Comment: i still don't understand why babel 2022 does those tings differently and babel prior to that does not. And, when and if i ever update to TL2022, will/could this new option break things?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137757/discussion-between-lupino-and-ulrike-fischer).

Comment: if you let babel (or fontspec) guess which script setting is needed for your font it can err. Fonts are curious and lots of them do things a bit different to the standard. If you want to be on the safe side, set everything explicitly.

Comment: Now `babel`  loads the identification data for all languages (including BCP 47 tags, now required by LaTeX), while formerly it was loaded only when explicitly requested, and some defaults for the `nil` language has been added.  This explain the change.